# Is there an algorithm in STL like std::unique which stores the amount of equal objects?

Tags: c++, std

The [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) algorithm keeps only unique elements in consecutive groups of elements. Meanwhile, sometimes it is useful to know how many *specific* elements were in the initial container. Like to make a convolution with number of elements and their amounts.

Is there such an algorithm in STL or some straightforward way to do this not considering writing the whole code from scratch (which is easy, but I want to reuse existing solutions as much as possible) and avoiding extra containers like `std::unordered_map`, etc.? The key is to have an easy and straightforward solution like `std::equal`.

It could seem like `std::unique` with an additional iterators to write amounts or making `std::unique` working with `std::pair` where the `first` will store the value and the `second` its amount.

**For example**

For container

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

as the result I'd like to have either two containers [1,2,1] and [2,2,2] where the first keep values and second one keeps their amounts in consecutive groups (in this case [1,2] and [4,2] could be an option, but this is slightly different topic) **or** one container like [{1,2}, {2,2}, {1,2}].

Comment: The natural brute-force way is probably for every element in the container, [count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) the number of occurrences.

Comment: What exactly do you want to produce? The number of groups of consecutive elements? Say, for the sequence `[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]`, what should be the correct result - 2, 3, something else? It's not quite clear what end result you wish to obtain.

Comment: This wouldn't be an algorithm; it would be a view that finds unique clusters whose elements are a range of such clusters.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, of course, as I stated in the question, this could be done. As well as std::equal could be done "in natural brute-force way" without STL. My question is only to know if I miss something ready to avoid reinventing the bicycle. With "ready" I mean an algorithm or some kind of their combinations like Nicol, probably suggests below.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I have updated the question. I need the number of elements in groups. Does it clarify?

Comment: @NicolBolas, will this view be simple or this is like to write my own brute-force solution? If it should be simple, could you please show the idea?

Comment: With the updated information in the question, the brute-force solution is a single iteration over the container, counting and collecting data as you go. I doubt you can get better than O(n) really. For the alternative solution with  [1,2] and [4,2], a single (unordered) map would be enough to keep the data (value as key, count as data). [The ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) might help, but would be more complex than a single and simple loop.

Comment: I can imagine a custom output iterator that counts consecutive elements and writes out {value, count} pairs, and passing that to `std::transform`. But a hand-written loop would be much more straightforward.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I see, but I am trying to say again and again that my question is about avoiding reinventing bicycles, not about programming simple task for a first grade programmer. I know how to implement brute-force version, but with this logic I might ask "why do we have std::unique, if we can implement it"? The idea to avoid situation when code reviewer will say "Why didn't you use existing algorithm or combination of them (like views in the answer below)?". I just asking to avoid reinventing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I try to avoid writing even simple code when straightforward library solutions are possible. The solution (like you suggested) in the answer below doesn't have explicit loop counters, conditions, comparisons, limits and other stuff where one can easily make a mistake. It is what I initially called "straightforward" and requires less time to read and debug when one accustomed to views and ranges. I don't argue with your way of handling this, I just explain my approach and cause of the question.

Comment: Sometimes there simply are no simple existing solutions, and the naive or brute-force and "first grade assignment" solution is perhaps the best? The ranges answer you accepted, is it really better in all possible ways? Is it easier to read and understand? Even at a quick glance? Is it easier to debug? Easier to maintain? Don't overcomplicate things, it just makes it harder for the next programmer to work on your code (which might be yourself in a year or two when you have forgotten all about it). Don't dismiss solutions just because they seem too simple.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, believe me or not, I say my people the same things word to word with one reservation; you should learn your tools and ask if necessary. What would you say if your programmer coded their own lower_bound just because they don't know about std::lower_bound? Would you be happy they spent hours for writing and debugging and finally anyway got worse solution? I still can't explain you the only point of my question, I want to know if the ready solution (algorithm or their combination) exist. That's all I need. Why this simple clarification is in your way?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, On your comments regarding "betterness" in all possible ways. In my experience, solutions very rarely could be "better in all possible ways"; when it comes to professional coding there are tradeoffs, like modularity against performance, sometimes. Is this solution better? Well, we haven't seen your solution to compare. Can you please post it and let's make comparisons in all terms like: amount of entities used, number of lines of code used, etc. One extra advantage, the developer will try a new tool and learn it, maybe some day it will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of `<ranges>`, you may want to use [`views::chunk_by`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/chunk_by_view)

```
auto l = {1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1};
auto r = l | std::views::chunk_by(std::ranges::equal_to{})
           | std::views::transform([](auto chunk) {
               return std::pair{chunk.front(), chunk.size()};
             });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v574aqnfe)

If you need to collect numbers and amounts separately, you can use [`views::keys`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/keys_view)/[`views::values`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/values_view)

```
auto numbers = r | std::views::keys;
auto amounts = r | std::views::values;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TqM4eqxhz)

Comment: Thank you. This one fits my need quite well. Two questions. (1) With this implementation wouldn't the performance on large amount of data (gigabytes) be worse than with simple brute-force loop? I mean, will this pipe generate the code close by performance? It is hard to see this at glance from the provided demo and its code. Any possible underwater stones from performance view like excessive copies, intermediate allocations, etc.? (2) Is there a way to implement similar which will return two separate containers - with numbers and with amounts?

Comment: @DamirTenishev I don't think there's an observable performance impact here, views don't store data so there's no allocation involved. There is no need to use a container that involves dynamic allocation, you can just use `views::keys/views::values` to get different views.

Comment: @Danir, the `r` presented here will work fine when `l` is an _input_range, but the separated `numbers` and `amounts` require a _forward_range, so it might be better to adapt your code to accept the pairs rather than separate ranges.